# Google API Request Limit

Tags: api, rest, google-api

Does anyone know where I can find Google API Request Limits for their different services?

On simulating 500+ concurrent users it seems to fail silently fairly often (maybe 1 in 10 loads)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is in their support resources. I am not aware of a central place, but it's all there. Searching the docs for "request limit" should usually do the trick.

The Geocoding API's limits for example can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#geocoder_limit).

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API Web Services and Google Static Maps API limits were cut effective a few days ago. Starting **October 1st 2011** commercial web sites and apps using **[Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#usagelimits)** for free receive:

- max of 2,500 calls/day, if modified using Styled Maps feature
- max of 25,000 calls/day in total

Fusion tables are preferable to the Google Maps API alone, particularly with respect to **[rate limits](http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide.html#Constraints)**:

> Applications using the Google Fusion Tables API can send a maximum of
>   5 requests per second to the Google Fusion Tables server.

Answer (score 0):

I think they removed the limit recently: can't even find a mention of it in documentation pages where I know for sure that it was mentioned and read about the limit removal somewhere this summer.

Even their new EULA states that their service is not limited but they remain free to limit it however they want at any moment.
500 concurrent users doesn't seem to be that much though, even if limitations where in place; are you sure it's Google what's failing?

Comment: Hey, Yeah I'm pretty sure - unless its something going wrong with curl processing the request, the result is completely blank when returned.